Make Material CheckBox Checkmark Color Black Instead of Transparent
I like the animation and the teal color of the default Material 3 CheckBox. However, the checked checkBox on a white background is not easily readable for those that are color blind.  I would like for the checkmark that is currently transparent to be black so that it is a black check on a teal background when checked.
I have played with different variations of checkboxes and tried to change the checkbox background, but nothing has looked remotely like what I want or the animation was missing.
Does anyone have any ideas of how I could do this without losing the animation? I am using XML

depends on what you're using, for xml based views you have
app:buttonIconTint  
app:buttonTint

if you're using Compose, you have
CheckboxColors(
   checkedCheckmarkColor: Color,
   uncheckedCheckmarkColor: Color,
...)

which can be used in the Checkbox Composable:
@Composable
fun Checkbox(
    checked: Boolean,
    onCheckedChange: ((Boolean) -> Unit)?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    colors: CheckboxColors = CheckboxDefaults.colors(),
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource? = null
): Unit

some useful links:

for XML
for Compose


Thanks for your response. Although this is good general information it doesn't really answer my question. buttonIconTint just changes the color of the icon and the transparent part (the checkmark) is still transparent. I am looking for a way to add black background so that when checked the now transparent checkmark appears black and the rest of the icon remains the original teal color.
